# Why won't Font Awesome icons load in my React Native Expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I'm trying to integrate Font Awesome into a React Native Expo app that I'm working on, but I keep getting the following error:

> console.error: "ERROR: icon not found for icon = ", "coffee"

I'm just following the instructions on the following GitHub page for React Native Font Awesome: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome

Specifically, first, I ran the following commands:

```
npm i --save react-native-svg #
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome
```

Those all ran fine. Then I added the following to my home screen code:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
...
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" />
```

Again, I'm just following the instructions on the GitHub page linked to above. When I do all that though, I get the error noted above. Accordingly to my `package.json`, I'm on `expo` version `~36.0.0`.

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Tried it in snack its not loading. So added fontawesome icons via react native vector icons and its working perfectly
Example : https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/moody-strawberries

Comment: I ran `npm install --save react-native-vector-icons`, then `react-native link`. Everything said it was successful. I then added `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';`, which worked, but when I did `<Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" /> `, I got the following error: `console.error: "fontFamily "FontAwesome" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync. ...`. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Hey sebastian... here is related thread (let me know if this dosen't help) ---------->https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/789

Comment: I tried what they recommended, which was deleting the `node_modules` folder and trying `npm i` again, but it just seemed to make things worse. After doing that, I got the following message when I ran `npm start`: `Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version: - react-native-svg - expected version range: 9.13.3 - actual version installed: ^12.0.3 Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages. To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]`

Comment: So I then ran the following: `expo install react-native-svg`. And now, when I even try to import `@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome`, then I then the following error: `Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run 'yarn' or 'npm install'.` Any ideas?

Comment: Decided to run an `npm start -c` this time, and now, I get the following error with the same code: `Unable to resolve module './elements/ForeignObject' from 'node_modules\react-native-svg\src\ReactNativeSVG.ts': ...`. Any ideas?

Comment: From thread you had to add this line
---->
import FontAwesome from '../node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf';

Answer (score 2):

```
import {faCoffee} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Just gave me a new, different error. Sorry.

Comment: what was the error? have you tried to delete the app and build it again?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was "easy", but also not so obvious.

Basically, because I'm using Expo to build my React Native app, I had to use the Expo version of Font Awesome. As such, I didn't need any of those npm modules I installed before. They could all be uninstalled.

In place of those modules, I added the following at the top of my file:

```
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

And then the following to get a Font Awesome icon to show up on the screen:

```
<FontAwesome name="times" />
```

That's all there was to it. I guess I was fundamentally taking the wrong approach to begin with. Sorry for all the confusion. Thanks again to everyone that helped.